# for_each but for setting each element to a value in C++

Tags: c++, stl, foreach

I have the following code to assign a value to all the elements of a vector:

```
x = 100;

for (int i=0;i<vect.size();i++)
{
    vect[i] = x;
}
```

It's straightforward enough, but I'm wondering if there is a function in the STL that does the same thing; something like for_each, but for assignment.

Comment: Personally, I always preferred `BOOST_FOREACH`, with which you can do `BOOST_FOREACH(int &i, vect) {i = x; }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`std::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/):

```
std::fill(vect.begin(), vect.end(), 100);
```

---

Note if you want to initialize a vector to have all the same value, you can use the appropriate constructor:

```
std::vector<int> v(5, 100); // 5 elements set to 100
```

`assign` can be used to "reset the vector", but if you're just making the vector, use the constructor.

Comment: If you want to fill an existing vector with fewer elements than it already has and trim the rest to save space then use the swap idiom: `vector<int>(3,25).swap(v);`

Comment: ^^ ... the swap idiom will trigger a reallocation, I should mention, but will result in less memory used for the vector. So ultimately it's a good idea only if your intention is to cut back on memory use, not to fill a vector with (coincidentally fewer) values.

Answer (score 7):

```
vect.assign(n, x);
```

`n` is the number of elements.

`x` is the value to fill with.

The difference from `std::fill` is that you supply the length for this. `std::fill` would use the previous length of the vector. (Actually, it would use whatever segment of the vector that you tell it to, but using `vect.begin()` and `vect.end()` as in the above example would use the previous length.) Depending on the situation, you will want to use one or the other.

Comment: The other difference is that `assign()` is a member of `vector` while `fill()` is part of the more generic algorithms library which works with any forward iterators (or an output iterator if you use a different signature).  I think could reasonably expect `vector::assign()` to perform better than `std::fill()`.

Comment: @Michael: Probably. The reason I chose `fill` was because it matches the code in the question, though arguably I suppose one could do `vect.assign(vect.size(), x);`. Then again, `std::fill` could be specialized for random access iterators, yielding the same result performance-wise.

Comment: @Michael and GMan: I doubt that most standard libraries optimize enough for it to make a difference in speed (although `assign` has the potential to be faster because it could potentially use SIMD, which I don't think `fill` could, unless the compiler is really smart). I think you would want to avoid `vect.assign(vect.size(), x)` because it might reallocate the internal array, depending on the implementation. The reason I chose `assign` was because it is the function that I use more, along with the constructor, which is very similar. `fill` probably makes more sense in this case.

Comment: `vect.assign(vect.size(), x)` is guaranteed not to reallocate. I'm sure all modern implementations will optimize `fill` for random access iterators, generating the same code as `vect.assign(vect.size(), x)`, and therefore getting the same optimizations. I'll test some stuff out later to make sure.